# What is the typical resistance of a piece of 1 cm^2 of carbon paper?

Tags: electrochemistry

I have been using carbon paper (Carbon sheet 99.8% from STERM CHEMICALS) to load catalysts for fuel cell study. Just now, I realized that for a 1 cm^2 piece the resistance is about 3 ohms!

Is that a typical value? I can't find any info on Google or the seller's webpage.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If there is no published resistance for that carbon sheet, then the best choice is to do exactly what you *have* done, i.e., measure the resistance *per square*. However, that specification **is** in given in the [Strem catalog](https://www.strem.com/uploads/resources/documents/carbon_booklet.pdf)! It might be difficult o find if you do not spell the company's name correctly.

Two notes:

1. Resistance of a uniform, homogeneous sheet is measured *per square*, not per cm2. Whether the sheet is 1 mm on a side, or 100 km on a side, the resistance from one edge to the other would be the same; in your case, 3 Ω. [Consider that making the separation wider between edges is exactly compensated by the increased length of the conducting sheet.]
2. "Carbon paper" referred, in English, to [paper with a mix of lampblack carbon and wax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_paper), though now it also applies carbon microfiber paper. For clarity, I suggest using the [name Strem uses in it's catalog](https://www.strem.com/uploads/resources/documents/carbon_booklet.pdf).